# Running Server not in UiThread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to run my ServerSocket and I know how to do it using Thread, but I want to start it not in Ui, so I was thinking about launch this server using AsyncTask.

I have code:

```
ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket();            
serversocket.execute();


public class ServerSocket extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        public void DataFetcher(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String data = null;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "server is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // make gui thread do some work
        }

    }
```

but it's not working, can anyone tell me what should I do?

I have ServerClient running using AsyncTask and i want also run my server liek that ,
here is my code for Client:

```
public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {   
      String dstAddress="..."
      int dstPort=8080;
      String response = "";

      MyClientTask(String addr, int port){
       dstAddress = addr;
       dstPort = port;
      }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
           Socket socket = null;           
           try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);                                   
           } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
           }finally{
            if(socket != null){
             try {
              socket.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
            }
           }
           return null;
          }
          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
          {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
          }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "server is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`Toast` runs on the main thread and since you can't update UI elements in a background `Thread` you can't call it from `doInBackgroud()`

You can do this in `onPostExecute()` or in `onProgressUpdate()` by calling `publishProgress()` in `doInBackground()`

If it still isn't working then define "but it's not working". That is not a very helpful summary of what is/isn't happening.

> I know how to do it using Thread, but I want to start it not in Ui

If you are running it in a separate `Thread` then it is **not** running on the UI `Thread`

Comment: Even if i put toast in onPostExecute() it doesnt work, i dont think i am using AsyncTask right i just need run server in Background. Code in post is incorrect.

Comment: ServerSocket serverSocket;

Comment: and that all for that moment i just want toast if server is up

Comment: then i will do more things

Comment: check my post i added more info

Comment: So what is not working? Have you put logs or breakpoints to see what results are/aren't correct?